# Cache moving versions

Tags: cache

Can i save a cache from 2.79 and use it in 2.8?

I am using 2.79 for the dynamic paint at the moment and was wondering if I can bring a cloth cache from 2.8 to my 2.79 file.
Or the opposite with a particle system into 2.8?

I am having rain effect a flag but since dynamic paint doesn't work on image sequence in 2.8 I am not sure how to do it.

Comment: What happens when you try? Anyway, regardless of outcome, frequently jumping versions for the same file is never healthy

Comment: It was more a question if you can export a cache file like i can with an object file. Because i have no problem exporting an obj file and just opening it in the other but i am unsure if the cache can be imported in the same way.

Comment: I’m having great difficulty using a 2.79 particle cache in 2.8. Trying to follow a tutorial to bring 2.79 Fracture Modifier scenes into 2.8. Particles completely changed in 2.8- a system where particles do not die within the frame range of the sim in 2.79, becomes one where the get borne in the wrong place and die before they should...